# can i edit lightswitch screen (or element of it like custom control) to load my entire HTML page?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

i want to load a HTML page to occupy the entire lightswitch screen

i tried this but i can't make the div to take the page (i tried to edit width and height of the custom control and of the div itself but this didn't work)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the custom control to a group layout item and stretching both to fit the container,

Comment: thanks, i think to design my entire HTML and embed it inside the screen using iframe but what i can't do is to access the iframe elements from js of the custom control.

how can i do that, or there is a better way to communicate  between my page and the light switch so i can get the data and view it to my page and take data from html page and store it to the intrinsic database?

Comment: It's best if you post this as a separate question, and start by telling us what you're trying to achieve, and why you think doing all of your html development inside a separate iframe is the best approach. All that LS will know is that it has a custom control, it's up to you to implement the render method and any code that's specific to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

i can make that using by editig the default style of lightswitch

```
element.innerHTML += '<div id ="mycontent" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"> </div>"';
document.getElementById("mycontent").innerHTML += 
'<object data="page.html" type="text/html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></object>';

$("object").parent().parent().css("width", "100%");
$("object").parent().parent().css("height", "1200px");

//to eliminate the header if you want to
$("span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("width", "0px");
$("span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("height", "0px");
```

...